# Scala: Could not find main class when running fat jar

Tags: java, scala, azure, dependencies, sbt

I recently got into some issues after I added two dependencies in my little Scala project. I can no longer run my project. `Error: Could not find or load main class a.b.c.DataExtractor`. I already spent the entire day looking for similar problems as the same error appeared in quite a lot of posts either here on other platforms.

My fat jar is being created with sbt assembly.

```
Seq(
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.12",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpmime" % "4.5.12",
  "org.apache.olingo" % "olingo-odata2-api" % "2.0.11",
  "org.apache.olingo" % "olingo-odata2-core" % "2.0.11",
  "com.azure" % "azure-security-keyvault-secrets" % "4.1.0",
  "com.azure" % "azure-identity" % "1.0.5",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.30"
  )
```

As soon as I add the `com.azure` dependencies, they come witha a lot more of them and I can no longer start up my project.

In my target/scala-2.11 folder I have the two needed jars:

- data-extractor-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- scala-library-2.11.12.jar

In order to start the app, I run the following 
`java -cp data-extractor-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:scala-library-2.11.12.jar -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG -verbose a.b.c.DataExtractor`

My guess is it's got something to do with the build of the assembly. I checked the produced artifact and the MANIFEST.MF file was displaying `Main-Class: a.b.c.DataExtractor` as expected, but still something is failing. I just can't put my finger of what is the source of the problem.

So, Scala 2.11.12, sbt 1.2.8 and Java 1.8.0_162, if that is relevant

Any information or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Was the main class also inside a JAR? Perhaps conflict resolution made it so that you ended up with a version of a library that has main under a different name?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok No, the main class is my own. It has the proper name inside the produced fat jar, with packages and everything. I'm even decompiling it and comparing it with the "simple fat-jar", the one without the dependencies to the Azure projects. Same thing, same code, same MANIFEST.MF file. Can't really see what's causing the problem

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is error during loading. Try to make your main class basically empty, so that it won't require loading other things from classloader. Check if errors still occurs.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thank you for your suggestions so far and your interest into this issue. I did manage to solve it after a lot of struggle. Please check the answer that I posted to find out more

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to solve this in the end with some sbt assembly magic in the build.sbt file I am also including the scala library files so I only need to specify the fat-jar for the `-cp` parameter.

```
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = true),
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*)     => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html"                                 => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "plugin.properties"                          => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties"                           => MergeStrategy.last
  case "module-info.class" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    xs match {
      case ("MANIFEST.MF" :: Nil) => MergeStrategy.discard
      // Concatenate everything in the services directory to keep GeoTools happy.
      case "mailcap" :: Nil => MergeStrategy.last
      case "mimetypes.default" :: Nil => MergeStrategy.last

      case ("services" :: _ :: Nil) =>
        MergeStrategy.concat
      // Concatenate these to keep JAI happy.
      case "javax.media.jai.registryFile.jai" :: Nil | "registryFile.jai" :: Nil |
           "registryFile.jaiext" :: Nil =>
        MergeStrategy.concat
      case name :: Nil => {
        // Must exclude META-INF/*.([RD]SA|SF) to avoid "Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes" exception.
        if (name.endsWith(".RSA") || name.endsWith(".DSA") || name.endsWith(".SF"))
          MergeStrategy.discard
        else
          MergeStrategy.first
      }
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first
    }
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```